# footer doesn't stay in 960 grid

Tags: css, footer, 960.gs

I'm working with the 960 grid system and I'm having trouble with keeping the footer inline with the grid, as well as at the bottom of the page. The following code is computed with a margin-left and a margin-right of 0px instead of auto-filling in the space between the edge of the page.

HTML

```
<footer class="botbar">
    <small class="contact">name address information</small>
    <small class="social">social media icons</small>
    <small class="humans">human info</small>
    <small class="copyright">&copy; info</small>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.botbar {
  /*properties of container_16*/
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
  /*my styling*/
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;}
.fcontact {
  /*properties of prefix_1*/
    padding-left:60px;
  /*properties of container_16+grid_4*/
    width:220px;
  /*properties of grid_4*/
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
.social {
  /*properties of prefix_1*/
    padding-left:60px;
  /*properties of grid_4*/
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
  /*properties of container_16+grid_4*/
    width:220px;
  /*properties of suffix_1*/
    padding-right:60px;}
.humans {
  /*properties of grid_4*/
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
  /*properties of container_16+grid_4*/
    width:220px;
  /*properties of suffix_1*/
    padding-right:60px;}
.copyright{
  /*properties of grid_16*/
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
  /*properties of container_16+grid_16*/
    width:960px;}
```

Comment: looks like I can add a <div class="bottom"> <footer>...</footer> where .bottom {clear: both; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
but why doesn't it work applied to the footer? do I HAVE to nest in order to do an absolute positioning and maintain the 960 format?

Answer (score 0):

solved it, was able to do the .bottom class and add it to footer so `<footer class="botbar bottom">` without needing a `<div>`